# How to get the process id (PID) of an app launched using `open` command on OSX?

Tags: macos, terminal

I've launched an application via the `open` command on the OSX command line like so:

```
open -a "/Applications/Adobe After Effects CC/Adobe After Effects CC.app"
```

I want to get the process id of that launched application.  Is there any way to do this reliably on OSX?  It doesn't seem `open` returns anything, so I'm not sure I can even pipe its result into something like `ps` to perform a `grep` operation.  I thought that maybe since the app is launched via the terminal I would know which app is the `frontmost`, but am doubting the reliability of that solution. Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After executing open -a, you can execute ps command. Doing a grep on the output of ps command gives info on process ID.

```
ps aux | grep -v grep |grep -i <application name> | awk '{print $2;}'
```

The one given below gives the elapsed time for the process.

```
ps aux -o etime,command | grep -v grep |grep -i <application name> | awk '{print $2, $12,$13}'
```

We can compare the elapsed time to know the pid of the recently launched one.

Comment: Thanks for that, but if I am launching new instances of the app with the `-n` flag, wouldn't your solution show multiple PIDs?

Comment: ya ... it will list all. I think the highest number/process ID should be the last launched one.

Comment: I'd recommend that you avoid using the `-n` flag. Most applications are not written with the assumption that multiple instances may exist at a time, and they may malfunction when used this way.

Comment: The output for following gives the Elapsed time for a process. ps aux -o etime,command | grep -v grep |grep "0xED"

Comment: @SeemaKadavan good stuff, see https://forums.adobe.com/message/9633995#9633995 where I show that a higher PID is not a proof of being more recent.

Answer (score 6):

**Activity Moniter**

You can use [Activity Moniter](https://support.apple.com/en-ca/guide/activity-monitor/welcome/mac). Located in /System/Applications/Utilities/Activity\ Monitor.app

Open the app, hit the search bar on the top and search for the app you want to get the PID of. [image: Example]

Comment: EDIT: I know this isn't "shell" like related, but hey, some people get this when they are searching. Perhaps this has an answer too :)

Answer (score 2):

These days, `pgrep -n $APPLICATION_NAME` seems like the easiest way to accomplish this. From the man page:

```
-n    Select only the newest (most recently started) of the matching processes.
-o    Select only the oldest (least recently started) of the matching processes.
```