# C header for Mac OS X open Command or equivalent

Tags: c++, c, macos

I read these already:

- [How to get the process id (PID) of an app launched using `open` command on OSX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25389495/how-to-get-the-process-id-pid-of-an-app-launched-using-open-command-on-osx)
- https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/open.1.html

I'm trying to get a PID out of the open command. We have an internal multi-platform C++ library allowing for example (overly simplifying):

```
pid = launch(char* command) 
// Many other parameters and variations (sync/async,timeout,stdout,stderr,stdin )
```

However on OS X, the library users often use as command:

```
Open myExe myArgs -F
```

It seems:

- there is no way to prevent the open command from detaching the child process. (problem for kill when timeout)
- there is no way to get child pid back

---

I'm very open to any solution:

- Is there a c header for the open command ? "man open" only gives the shell command and the open "file" c function. Maybe this function would give me more control
- Is there a way to "simulate" the behavior of open in c++ when calling execve? I mean cleaning cache and putting application in the foreground (-F and **not** -g )
- ...

Comment: I'm inclined to guess that OSX's `open` command is simply a program built on top of the ordinary [`fork` /] `exec` infrastructure, not a wrapper for any higher-level library function.  Certainly the (POSIX-)standard function of the same name -- which OSX does provide -- has very different purpose and behavior.

Comment: Does giving open the `-W` option cause it not to detach the child process?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick No. It seems it has the pid internally and waits for it. My lib returns the pid of "open" instead of myExe. Killing "open" does not kill the launched process. This was of course the first thing we tried!

Comment: @JohnBollinger the posix function of the same name is nothing related, it opens a file descriptor. http://linux.die.net/man/2/open

Comment: OK, so your overall goal is to be able to kill an application launched by open, is that correct?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick yes. Kill it. But also get back the stdout/stderr.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick I could also prevent the user from using 'open' if I was able to provide the same services (foreground launching and clean app cache) Hence they'd launch the exe directly and everything would be fine.

Comment: @user2346536, you seem to be using the term "detach" in an unconventional way.  If the `Open` command launches a child process and is *able* to wait for it, then the child is, perforce, not detached.  Moreover, you should then be able to identify the child in the process list by its parent process's ID.  And no, I would not expect killing the parent to cause the child to die, but if you do kill the parent then the child will be reparented, which makes it much harder to identify.

Comment: @user2346536, as for capturing the child's `stdout` and `stderr`, you are likely stuck.  These are almost certainly redirected to `/dev/null` or a similar black hole by `Open`.  If you (or the user) want to receive the data written to these streams by the ultimate program, then `Open` is simply the wrong tool for launching that program.

Comment: @JohnBollinger when the I kill from the library, I kill the process group id of open. getpgid(pid_t pid); then kill this pgid. I would expect the child to die too...

Comment: @JohnBollinger it is the wrong tool. The best shot would be to get a way to simulate open. And this is certainly very mac specific. Indeed, my user told me that, If a GUI process is opened using fork/execv it does not receive click events of many kind... This is mac Desktop Environment Specific. Only open without -g will do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Coming back to write my workaround answer, i do not like it as I do need to use some cocoa stuffs but it works...

I have obtained the desired "foreground" behaviour and got a Pid back with the following code:

```
NSString * arg1 = @"--my_arg";
NSString * arg2 = @"arg_value";
NSArray  * myArray2 = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:arg1,arg2,nil];

NSMutableDictionary* dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[dict setObject:myArray2 forKey:NSWorkspaceLaunchConfigurationArguments];

bURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"/path/to/appli.app"];
NSRunningApplication * inst = [ws launchApplicationAtURL:bURL options:NSWorkspaceLaunchNewInstance configuration:dict error:nil];
pid_t pid = [inst processIdentifier];
```

in Xcode, you can use the above code in my file.mm whose signature is declared in my file.h. Xcode will manage the cocoa stuffs automagically.